# Error en $FILES durante la subida de un archivo: Undefined array key

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un menú donde envío unos documentos, por ahora es algo simple, solo quiero imprimir algo sencillo como en el código para saber si hay conexión o no.

he visto videos donde hago exactamente lo mismo pero a mi me sale el error (Undefined array key "vida") y a ellos no.

El include está bien porque me funciona en los demás archivos.

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```php
<?php

include "conexion.php";

if(isset($_POST['subir'])){
    if(file_exists($_FILES['vida']['tmp_name'])){
        echo "Se ha subdio";
    }else{
        echo "NO";
    }
}
```

**CÓDIGO HTML**

```html
<form action="../../conexión/datos2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">

        <!--HOJA DE VIDA-->
        <h5 class="text-center">Hoja de Vida:</h5>
        <input type="file" name="vida"/><br><br>
<!--ENVIAR DOCUMENTOS-->
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="subir" value="Enviar Documentos"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que estas haciendo mal? para empezar, pusiste un titulo nada descriptivo.. y segundo, decis que tenes un error, pero no lo mostras.. usa el boton [edit], pone un titulo mejor y agrega todos los detalles de tu problema en la pregunta...

Comment: Tienes un error tipografico en el <form>. Revísa bien ese elemento y compáralo con [este ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-438)

Comment: `<form enctype="multipart/formdata" action="../../conexión/datos2.php" method="post" > ` Así lo dejé y el error sigue

Comment: Pues claro que sigue, cambiar el orden de los atributos no altera el producto.  Lée bien el enlace que te he pasado antes, sobretodo la **Nota** que aparece en el texto que se muestra a continuación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar "controlar/evitar" este tipo de error de ejecución comprobando que ciertas posiciones de un *array* existen antes de tratar de accederlas, p.e.

```
function canLoadFile(string $indexName = 'vida'): bool
{
    if (!isset($_FILES[$indexName]) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!isset($_FILES[$indexName]['tmp_name']) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

if (file_exists(canLoadFile('vida') && $_FILES['vida']['tmp_name'])){
    echo "Se ha subdio";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

Con esto evitas un fallo del lenguaje, pero aun no tienes tu fichero.
Puedes hacer debug hasta encontrar el punto de fallo, por ejemplo, imprimer en que línea de `canLoadFile()` se devuelve false, para ver que no tienes, o imprimir todo el contenido de `$_FILES`:

```
print_r($_FILES ?? 'NO _FILES content');
```

*NO _FILES content* se imprimirá si la superglobal `$_FILES` es `null`.

Comment: muchas gracias a todso, ERROR CORREGIDO